# Test Django app using models from a second app

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

When I run my Django tests for an app, only the models for that app are loaded.

My app has a dependency on a second app and requires that the tables for the second app's models be present in the database.

How is this achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by "only the models for that app are loaded"? Django's test runner runs syncdb, which creates database tables for all installed apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time your create an app, you need to add it to the installed apps, for do that open your setting file, and add your app to installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'your_test_app',
    'here_goes_your_other_app'
)
```

Then close the server, run `python manage.py syncdb` and try.